# Error when I call GetScheduler (Cannot implicitly convert type. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?))

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use the GetScheduler() in my code and I my overall goal is to archive a method that sends out an email at a certain time of the day.

Below is a codesnipet of where it goes wrong:

```
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInSeconds(30)
                .OnEveryDay()
              )
             .ForJob(emailJob)
             .WithIdentity("trigger1")
             .StartNow()
             .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?") // Time : Every 1 Minutes job execute
             .Build();

        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();// this is where it goes wrong
        sc.ScheduleJob(emailJob, trigger);
        sc.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check :

```
IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler().Result
```

Because GetScheduler returns `Task<IScheduler>`